# Whitelisting Salesforce IP addresses

Tags: administration, security, admin, ip, ip-whitelisting

We want to integrate Salesforce with one of our in-house applications. However, my networking team does not want to open the IP address (128.245.0.0/16 means 16,000 IPs) . How can we restrict the IP addresses as little as possible?

How can we make this happen for them?

Answer (score 1):

From official documentation here is the list of IP addresses that Salesforce uses https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1, including the one you pointed out. Some of them are really broad.

You can try to test what IP ranges Salesforce uses for your location and try whitelist only them.

You can also contact Salesforce support and figure out how you can configure smaller list of IP ranges