# Programatically fetch Salesforce IP Addresses and Domains to Allow

Tags: ip, public, ip-whitelisting

I would like to get public IP ranges from https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321501&type=1 in a programmatic manner.

Web scrapping is a solution but it has its disadvantages. Looking for some other options, if possible

NB: I found a similar question but I would like a more automatic approach to this if possible: [Whitelisting Salesforce IP addresses](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/349080/whitelisting-salesforce-ip-addresses)

Comment: IPv4 address exhaustion occurred in 2015, so it is highly unlikely that any new IPv4 addresses will be added at any point in the future; you're probably wasting your time as it is. Go with the screen scraping and move on to more important things.

Comment: If you are interested, there is an [idea to upvote](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdevhUAB/salesforce-ip-address-ranges-api).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Note from the article that Hyperforce IPs are not distributed publicly.